# Prefixing custom CSS classes when using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I read someone was using Bootstrap, prefixing their custom CSS class names with a letter, a dash or an underscore, just to make it immediately obvious that they're custom.

E.g.: `<div class="col-sm-12 my-block-photo">` or `<div class="col-sm-12 _block-photo">`

So they'd then have all their custom classes prefixed with `my-` or `_`.

Is this going to backfire me? Is there an agreed upon convention of some kind? No matter what I searched, I couldn't find anything.

I heard about [BEM](https://en.bem.info), but it is [sometimes criticised](https://www.reddit.com/r/css/comments/73zu80/how_to_write_better_css_with_bem/dnuen2z/) for being overcomplicated, and overall there must be a reason it (seemingly) isn't widespread.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't agree. Asking "what's the best solution" can be opinion-based, but asking "what are the best practices adopted" isn't

Comment: "Best" is *entirely* opinion-based. but this is **too broad** either way.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354

Comment: BEM is criticized because it ends up creating a very long class name for the nested selector. My suggestion is to define your own separator for modifiers and elements.  For example use `_` instead `__`.

Comment: @CristianTraìna Best practices are, by definition, opinion.

Comment: @TylerH how about conventions or coding standards?

Comment: @aexl Also primarily opinion-based, unless they are declared in a spec somewhere as the correct way to do something. E.g. in Python, asking "what's the most Pythonic way to do this" is off-topic, but asking "what indentation do I need to get this Python code to work" is not, because Python *requires* specific indentation for different lines in order to work correctly.

Comment: I don't want to drag the comments in a talk about what's too ok and what's not. But a best practice is a **shared** opinion among developer, that it becomes a standard *de facto*. Asking why you should avoid global variables in JavaScript, for example, is **not** opinion based

Answer (score 1):

What's custom for you it's third party for someone other, and if two parts adopt the same convention, it's like not applying any convention at all.

If you are facing this problem, BEM is a good solution for it. If you aren't facing this problem and maybe you are just adopting one CSS framework, then you shouldn't care about it.

If your web-app is bigger and it involves different libraries from different teams, you can consider namespacing custom style:

```
.app-block-photo {
  img {

  }
}
```

In the above example, I used *SCSS* to don't repeat the same token too many times.

Another solution, if your web application is really too big, is adopting a framework that implements style encapsulation, like *Angular*.